# Error 500 with euca2ools UEC (enterprise cloud)

Tags: uec

I have been setting up Ubuntu Enterprise Cloud.

When I visit "192.168.2.14:8443" in my browser I get:

[image]

But when I visit "192.168.2.14:8773" (which is the url of euca2ools, right?) I get:

[image: dl.dropbox.com/u/182509/Screenshots/0e.png]

Whats wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Can you clarify what you mean by, But when I visit "192.168.2.14:8773"....  As you shouldn't be visiting that URL from your browser.  It is to use against euca2ools application for controlling your cloud.